# Could an html editor insert jQuery elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, execcommand

I've been playing with making an html editor with javascript functions:

So I have a very basic editor with a "bold" button which with I can make whatever text is selected bold, this is fine (I also have a number of other buttons too, but for simplicity and shortness of code I've missed them all out)

```
<head>
    <script>
        var editorDoc;
            function InitEditable () {
                var editor = document.getElementById ("editor");
                editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document;          
                var editorBody = editorDoc.body;

                if ('contentEditable' in editorBody) {
                    editorBody.contentEditable = true;
                }
                else {
                    if ('designMode' in editorDoc) {
                        editorDoc.designMode = "on";                
                    }
                }
            }

            function ToggleBold () {
                editorDoc.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body  onload="InitEditable ();">
    <button type="button" onclick="ToggleBold ();">Bold</button>
    <iframe  contenteditable="true" id="editor"></iframe>
</body>
```

However, something I was really interested in being able to implement would be adding a button which could insert, say, an accordion when pressed

This would then have to add other bits of script (I imagine) to be able to run each accordion (if you had more than one)

Although I haven't had much of a go at doing this myself yet, I was hoping to get a little insight into whether or not it's possible before starting

Comment: I have done it before. As long as you define some templates, you can add everything.

Comment: Do I need to initialise anything in a different way, or should it work with the way I have it set up above?

Comment: You have to define your templates and functions you will need to insert, edit, etc. It takes a lot of time.